# (0,y.StackNavigator) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I was trying to use the react-navigation StackNavigator, and backtracked my code multiple times but couldn't find the issue. I was trying to build a simple navigation menu using this function for ios.

I'm using expo. So I started this project by creating a new expo project through terminal with the command "create-react-native-app testExpo". As shown below I modified the App.js a bit then created a screens folder -> then created two screens: "HomeScreen" and "LoginScreen"
These are the pictures of my code and the error

https://i.ibb.co/fQ9fjf2/Screen-Shot-2019-01-10-at-9-02-54-AM.png

https://i.ibb.co/7Xtx6jM/Screen-Shot-2019-01-10-at-9-03-01-AM.png

https://i.ibb.co/C8xbBVY/Screen-Shot-2019-01-10-at-9-03-07-AM.png

//Error picture
https://i.ibb.co/chgwYHT/Simulator-Screen-Shot-i-Phone-X-2019-01-10-at-08-59-08.png

```
App.js

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

    import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
    import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <AppNavigator />
        );
      }
    }


    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
      LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
      HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen}
    })

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });


HomeScreen.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Text,
           View,
           StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

       class HomeScreen extends Component{
         render() {
           return(
             <View>
                <Text>This is the home screen</Text>
             </View>
           );
         }
       }

       export default HomeScreen;

LoginScreen.js

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Text,
             View,
             StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

       class LoginScreen extends Component{
         render() {
           return(
             <View>
                <Text>This is the login screen</Text>
             </View>
           );
         }
       }

       export default LoginScreen;
```

I expect the app to launch with multiple screens to the applications.

Comment: Plz do not post images of code. You could read [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) why it is bad.

Comment: The error says there is no such thing as `StackNavigator` in react-navigation any more.  Read the docs [`createStackNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#api-definition)

Comment: Thank you Yury. And also Ill make sure to remove the images and post my code right now